# I am trying to extract values and place them in a .db to use later, however my code has bugged and I can no longer even load SQLite

Tags: sqlite, ironpython, revitpythonshell

Using :
-IronPython
-AutoDesk 
-Revit (PyRevit)
-Revit API 
-SQLite3

My code is as follows:

```
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    print("connected")

    Insert_Volume = """INSERT INTO Column_Coordinates
(x, y, z)
VALUES
(1, 2, 3)"""
count = c.execute(Insert_Volume)
    conn.commit()
    print("Volume values inserted", c.rowcount)
    c.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table", error)
finally:
    if (conn):
        conn.close()
        print("The SQLite connection is closed")'''
```

This code used to work within PyRevit, but now does not, with the following error:

`Exception : System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly IronPython.SQLite`

Please advise, this is one of the early steps of a large project and therefore is delaying my work quite a bit.

I look forward to your reply.

Comment: What are your `import` statements?

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply. my import statements are as follows: ```import clr  import sqlite3```       apparently I cannot start a new line in replies but both statements are on separate lines

Comment: It seems the error is thrown by the `import sqlite3` import statement (would be worth updating your question to include all overhead statements). After a little digging, I got it a step further but it seems it could be a problem importing the sqlite3 package from IronPython